# API 21 Sliding tabs activity

Tags: android, eclipse, android-tabs

I want to have two tabs to navigate between Fragments, I did it with the old method but now with API 21 all methods are deprecated. I searched a lot but I didn't found any tutorial or sample. I try the SlidingTabs sample from Google but it's not built for Eclipse so I don't know how to integrate it in my app. Can someone help me? Maybe send me a link to a basic tutorial? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a `ViewPager` you are talking about and not a `NavigationDrawer` type of thing, it continues to work well on API-21.

Take a look at [IOSched application's code](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/SlidingTabStrip.java) for a "Google Play" like ViewPager indicator.

**EDIT**

Yes `setNavigationMode` is deprecated as a method and as a UI/UX pattern.

From [the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setNavigationMode(int)):

```
This method was deprecated in API level 21.
Action bar navigation modes are deprecated and not supported by inline toolbar action bars.
Consider using other common navigation patterns instead.
```

Which links to [common navigation patterns](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html).

**EDIT2**

Fixed iosched application code link.

Comment: I implemented it, nothing is deprecated on my side. Please specify.

Comment: I try to use a ViewPager but setNavigationMode is deprecated.

Comment: Yes, `setNavigationMode` is deprecated as a method and as a UI/UX pattern. If you look for an alternative (not deprecated), re-think your UI/UX, don't search for a not deprecated `setNavigationMode` method, because it does not exists AFAIK. That is why NavigationDrawers and ViewPagers are encouraged.

Comment: I want to achieve something exactly like the new Google Contacts app, can I achieve it only with a ViewPager?

Comment: Sure (I did it). Only stock `ViewPager` and a tab strip the way the IOSched app did.

Comment: I finally did it! Turns out you have the best solution! Thank you very much and sorry for wasting your time!

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) out, it may help you , it's a very well done menu for navigate through fragments

Comment: I don't want to use external libraries, I want to do it the right way with Android widgets...

Answer (score 1):

Just import those 2 classes : [SlidingTabStrip](https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/src/com.example.android.common/view/SlidingTabStrip.html) and [SlidingTabLayout](https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/src/com.example.android.common/view/SlidingTabLayout.html) in your project to have tabs in your application. You can take a look at the sample project to see how it is used.

Very simple to use. First import those 2 classes in your project and in your xml layout(my_layout.xml), add the SlidingTabLayout. I also added a viewPager in case you want to use it with a ViewPager :

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"      
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    tools:context="MyActivity">

      <SlidingTabLayout
            android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

     <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/my_pager" />  

</LinearLayout>
```

In your activity,

```
public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
      private SlidingTabLayout slidingTabLayout;
      private ViewPager viewPager;

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);         

         viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.my_pager);
         viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

         slidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout)findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
         slidingTabLayout.setViewPager(viewPager);
     }
}
```

And then you can define your adapter that will added to the SlidingTabLayout. For instance :

```
public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private static final int FRAGMENT_1 = 0;
    private static final int FRAGMENT_2 = 1;
    private static final int FRAGMENT_3 = 2;

    public MyAdapter (FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        switch (i){
            case FRAGMENT_1 : return new Fragment1();
            case FRAGMENT_2 : return new Fragment2();
            case FRAGMENT_3 : return new Fragment3();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case FRAGMENT_1 : return "Fragment 1 Title";
            case FRAGMENT_2 : return "Fragment 2 title";
            case FRAGMENT_3 : return "Fragment 3 Title";
        }
        return super.getPageTitle(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: I get an error: Fragment1() can't be resolved... what do I have to do?  btw thanks for your help!

Comment: Replace Fragment1,2 and 3 with your fragments for your apps. They are here for an example purpose only

Comment: I did it but my app crashes at launch, this is the error: 12-02 22:23:52.400: E/AndroidRuntime(15558): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class SlidingTabLayout

Comment: In the xml layout, put the slidingTabLayout with his full package. Like for instance org.myclass.view.SlidinTabLayout

Comment: Do you try it? Because now the app doesn't crash but the swype it's not fluid, it gets stuck between tabs and if I tap on a tab it doesn't change fragment.

Comment: This snippet I gave came from an app I am developping. I'll check later to see if it's workin properly and give you a  full answer. But normally, everything should work.

Comment: I want to achieve something exactly like the new Google Contacts app.